# How to Assign rel="cat" and rel="tag" in Breadcrumbs

Tags: php, wordpress, breadcrumbs, rel

Currently I'm building a new WP theme. I'm a designer and have only basic knowledge of PHP. So  for breadcrumbs, I used [Dimox's script](http://dimox.net/wordpress-breadcrumbs-without-a-plugin/).

But from an SEO point of view, I want to add the rel="cat" and rel="tag" to categories and tag links respectively in the breadcrumbs. I asked him, but he couldn't provide a solution. So if any WP developer can help me out in this it would be great.

Here is the Exact piece of code for the category link.

```
else {
        $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];
        echo get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
        echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;
      }
```

So I want to assign a rel="cat" tag to the category link which is created by the **get_the_category** function.

Comment: Checkout the [Breadcrumb NavXT (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/breadcrumb-navxt/).

Comment: Err, theme, plugin - all the same in Wordpress. Just included code.

Comment: This is not an "ask for code", do some code for me forum. In which problem did you ran while you tried to change the code. Please highlight the lines you've got a problem with. What went wrong?

Comment: Ok. Here is the SPECIFIC piece of code,

`else {
$cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];
echo get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;
}`

In that I want to assign rel="cat" tag to the category link i.e. **get_the_category** function

Comment: What did you try? What did not work? Add it to your question please, incl. the code.

Comment: Added the specific piece of code @hakre.

Comment: Your code is not about link output, you're looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line `45` of the [original code](http://dimox.net/wordpress-breadcrumbs-without-a-plugin/) to:

```
if ($cat->parent != 0){
    $parents = array_reverse(get_ancestors($cat->cat_ID, 'category'));
    foreach($parents as $parent_id){
        $parent = get_category($parent_id);
        echo '<a rel="cat" href="'.get_category_link($parent->cat_ID).'" title="'.esc_attr(sprintf(__( "View all posts in %s" ), $parent->name)).'">'.$parent->name.'</a> '.$delimiter.' ';
    }
}

echo '<a rel="cat" href="'.get_category_link($cat->cat_ID).'" title="'.esc_attr(sprintf(__( "View all posts in %s" ), $cat->name)).'">'.$cat->name.'</a> '.$delimiter.' ';
```

Comment: Tried it @Shef. But it didn't work. There wasn't any PHP error neither anything changed.

Comment: @Mani Viswanathan: Was the tag `rel="cat"` added to the links?

Comment: Nope. I again clarify I want rel="cat" tag on the category links in my single posts AND NOT on the "Category" page/archives. 

So the final result would look like 
[Home](http://myblog.com) » [Post Category](http://myblog.com/category/post-category) » Post Title

In which the Post Category link has the rel="cat" tag.

Comment: @Mani: In that case, you should change line `45` with the updated code above. :)

Comment: Tried that aswell. It entirely removed the Category link.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Worked perfectly :)